# How many non decreasing sequence of length k is possible?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

If we have a set like this { 1A ,2A ,2B, 3A, 3B, 3C}, how many non decreasing sequence is possible, such that number in left is less than number in right of length k?
i.e, 
Length = 2 then the following sequence are possible: 
**1A 1A,
1A 2A,
1A 2B,
1A 3A,
1A 3B,
1A 3C,
2A 2B,
2B 2A,
2A 3A,
.....
3C 3C** 
in total 25 combinations would be possible.

Comment: You allowed  1A 1A. So objects may repeat?  Is 2A considered less than 2B? Is 2B considered less than 3A? If so, why were the objects not called 1,2,3,4,5,6? I am puzzled by the $25$ part, suspect there may only be $21$.  Or are you allowing 2B, 2A?

Comment: Yes, 2A 2B and 2B 2A - both are non decreasing sequence. We worry only about the number and not about the character. A,B are just used to denote that there are 2 elements of with value 2. And, yes, objects can repeat.

Comment: How come **3A2A** comes in the sequence ?

Comment: infinite !!!!!!! $1A,1A,1A,........................................$

Comment: @true blue anil: Sorry, that was a mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: @alkabary : Length = 2. We restrict by length.

Comment: it is the same as if you considered the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ meaning that $1A = 1,2A = 2,2B =3,3A =4,3B =5,3C = 6$

Comment: Thats where the problem is. 2A 2B & 2B 2A is possible but here 2 3 is possible but not 3 2.

Answer (score 0):

Put X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 and compute for a few values of k. E.g. for k = 2, you have

XX = 1, XY = 2, XZ = 3, YY = 4, YZ = 6, ZZ = 9, giving your total of 25

Similarly, for k = 3, compute XXX, XXY, XXZ, XYY, XYZ, XZZ, YYY, YYZ,YZZ & ZZZ, and sum up.

Discern commonality between successive values of k, and work out through recursion.

You will get **$f_n = 3f_{n-1} - 2f_{n-2} + 3^n$**,

with **$f_0 = 1, f_1 = 6$** as initial values